# Is there a way to include shell scripts in a Python package with pyproject?

Tags: python, setuptools, packaging, setup.py, pyproject.toml

Previously with `setup.py` you could just add

```py
setuptools.setup(
...
    scripts=[ "scripts/myscript.sh" ]
)
```

and the shell script was just copied to the path of the environment. But with the new `pyproject` scpecification, this seems to not be possible any more. According to the [Python specification of entry points](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/entry-points/) and the [setuptools specification](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/entry_point.html#entry-points-syntax), only python functions that will be wrapped later, are allowed. Does anyone know a simple way of doing this like in `setup.py`? Or at least simpler than just doing a python function that calls the shell script with subprocess, which is what I think I will do if there's no simpler way.

Comment: It is probably still supported in setuptools. You do not have to move to `pyproject.toml`. You can keep using `setup.py` or at least `setup.cfg`. -- But it is true, that it does not seem to be standardized, not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably using the [`script-files` field of the `[tool.setuptools]` section](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/pyproject_config.html#setuptools-specific-configuration) should work:

```ini
[tool.setuptools]
script-files = ["scripts/myscript.sh"]
```

It was not standardized in [*PEP 621*](https://peps.python.org/pep-0621/), so it belongs in a setuptools-specific section.

Setuptools marks it as deprecated, but personally I would assume that it is safe to use for the next couple of years at least. It seems like such scripts are standardized in the [wheel file format](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/binary-distribution-format/), so it is a bit strange that they are not in `pyproject.toml`'s `[project]` section. Maybe it will be added later, but that is just speculation.

***Reference***:

- https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/pyproject_config.html#setuptools-specific-configuration
- https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/binary-distribution-format/
- https://discuss.python.org/t/whats-the-status-of-scripts-vs-entry-points/18524

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I wasn't able to find that option. But since it says it's deprecated, I think I will ask to them if they are planning to support such a feature. I was migrating to pyproject in order to avoid deprecated packaging options, so I think I will try to avoid that one.

Comment: @ZJaume I found a related discussion here: https://discuss.python.org/t/whats-the-status-of-scripts-vs-entry-points/18524 -- If you feel like it, I guess you could ask your follow-up questions there (it will likely get read by people not only from setuptools but packaging in general (pip, wheel, etc.), and the discussion is not that old, so I think it is fair to post on this thread).